# Google Maps API Is Not Loading Properly

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I am having an issue with my code and loading an embedded Google Maps API with styles. Please see my code below and the screenshots of what happens when I load the web page.

```
<section class="container-fluid text-center">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col">
                <div id="map" style="height: 100%;
            width: 750px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


            <script>
                function initMap(){
                    var latlng = { lat:40.589493, lng:-75.603426 };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map', {
                    center: latlng,
                        zoom: 8,

                }));
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map
                });
                marker.addListener('click', function() {
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                }
            </script>

            <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqthU.png

Comment: are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No. Only when I double click on the map is when I get the following error in console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'zoom' of null
    at Object.onClick (map.js:11)
    at HTMLDivElement.Wm.F._.Dm.Pa (common.js:63)
onClick @ map.js:11
Wm.F._.Dm.Pa @ common.js:63

Answer (score 1):

be sure your map div has  a proper height and width

```
<div class="col">
    <div id="map" style='width: 400px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>
```